# How can I sort where no character comes first?

Tags: sqlite, sorting, flutter, listview, stream-builder

I have a flutter app that I am working on where my TextFormField has to query an sqlite database and display a list of words (using a stream and ListView). Because I thought it was the general default and it is how my database is organized already I didn't write any code for sorting.

I have a problem though, when somebody types something like "the" the list shows up as follows:

- themselves
- then
- there
- these
- the

Why is "the" the last word? Does no character usually come after z? How can I make it come first? I would like my list to look like this:

- the
- themselves
- then
- there
- these

Is there something that I can set in the sqlite part or the listView part or somewhere that will fix this?

Comment: "_Because I thought it was the general default and it is how my database is organized already I didn't write any code for sorting._" This is your problem. While it sometimes "looks that way", a database **isn't** "_organized already_"... it's essentially a "bag" of records, and **unless you specify an order** you are not guaranteed to **get** an order. If you _impose_ sorting on those results (using an `ORDER BY` clause: see [Select syntax](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html), `the` should come ahead of all the others.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
select * 
from your_table
where col like '%the%'
order by case when col = 'the' then 1 else 2 end,
         col
```

Comment: Those are just an example of the words that I need to sort. The database is quite large.

Comment: If you have an index on `col` then it should be fine